# iText error while check pdf PDF/A-1A with java

Tags: java, itext, standards-compliance, pdfa

I am  writting in reference to an error I get while a signing a concrete pdf file with Java iText libraries version 5.5.3.

Adobe Pro verifies the conformance and tell me that conformance has been verified but iText tell me that "Annotation of type /Widget should have Contents key".

You can get the concrete file at http://www.boe.es/boe/dias/2014/08/06/pdfs/BOE-A-2014-8500.pdf

I post below the trace I get:

```
Caused by: com.itextpdf.text.pdf.PdfAConformanceException: Annotation of type /Widget should have Contents key.
at com.itextpdf.text.pdf.internal.PdfA1Checker.checkAnnotation(PdfA1Checker.java:462)
at com.itextpdf.text.pdf.internal.PdfAChecker.checkPdfAConformance(PdfAChecker.java:219)
at com.itextpdf.text.pdf.internal.PdfAConformanceImp.checkPdfIsoConformance(PdfAConformanceImp.java:71)
at com.itextpdf.text.pdf.PdfWriter.checkPdfIsoConformance(PdfWriter.java:3426)
at com.itextpdf.text.pdf.PdfWriter.checkPdfIsoConformance(PdfWriter.java:3422)
at com.itextpdf.text.pdf.PdfAnnotation.toPdf(PdfAnnotation.java:999)
at com.itextpdf.text.pdf.PdfIndirectObject.writeTo(PdfIndirectObject.java:158)
at com.itextpdf.text.pdf.PdfWriter$PdfBody.write(PdfWriter.java:420)
at com.itextpdf.text.pdf.PdfWriter$PdfBody.add(PdfWriter.java:398)
at com.itextpdf.text.pdf.PdfWriter$PdfBody.add(PdfWriter.java:373)
at com.itextpdf.text.pdf.PdfWriter$PdfBody.add(PdfWriter.java:369)
at com.itextpdf.text.pdf.PdfWriter.addToBody(PdfWriter.java:843)
at com.itextpdf.text.pdf.PdfStamperImp.addAnnotation(PdfStamperImp.java:1389)
at com.itextpdf.text.pdf.PdfStamperImp.addAnnotation(PdfStamperImp.java:1401)
at com.itextpdf.text.pdf.PdfSignatureAppearance.preClose(PdfSignatureAppearance.java:1283)
```

Thanks in advance for any reply.

Answer (score 2):

I have tried applied sample from here (http://itextpdf.com/book/digitalsignatures20130304.pdf, page 29) to your PDF document and everything seems to work fine.
The only exceptions in code are:

1. Create PdfAStamper instead of PdfStamper:

   ```
   PdfAStamper stamper = PdfAStamper.createSignature(reader, os, '\0', PdfAConformanceLevel.PDF_A_1B);
   ```
2. Set font to PdfSignatureAppearance so that font can be embedded:

   ```
   appearance.setLayer2Font(FontFactory.getFont("FreeMonoBold.ttf", BaseFont.WINANSI, BaseFont.EMBEDDED, 12));
   ```
3. Set output intents:

   ```
   ICC_Profile icc = ICC_Profile.getInstance(new FileInputStream("sRGB Color Space Profile.icm"));
   stamper.getWriter().setOutputIntents("Custom", "", "http://www.color.org", "sRGB IEC61966-2.1", icc);
   ```

Here's a complete code:

```
static public void sign(String src, String dest, Certificate[] chain, PrivateKey pk, String digestAlgorithm, String provider, MakeSignature.CryptoStandard subfilter, String reason, String location) throws GeneralSecurityException, IOException, DocumentException {
    // Creating the reader and the stamper
    PdfReader reader = new PdfReader(src);
    FileOutputStream os = new FileOutputStream(dest);
    PdfAStamper stamper = PdfAStamper.createSignature(reader, os, '\0', PdfAConformanceLevel.PDF_A_1B);
    // Creating the appearance
    PdfSignatureAppearance appearance = stamper.getSignatureAppearance();
    appearance.setLayer2Font(FontFactory.getFont("FreeMonoBold.ttf", BaseFont.WINANSI, BaseFont.EMBEDDED, 12));
    appearance.setReason(reason);
    appearance.setLocation(location);
    appearance.setVisibleSignature(new Rectangle(36, 748, 144, 780), 1, "sig");
    ICC_Profile icc = ICC_Profile.getInstance(new FileInputStream("sRGB Color Space Profile.icm"));
    stamper.getWriter().setOutputIntents("Custom", "", "http://www.color.org", "sRGB IEC61966-2.1", icc);
    // Creating the signature
    ExternalDigest digest = new BouncyCastleDigest();
    ExternalSignature signature = new PrivateKeySignature(pk, digestAlgorithm, provider);
    MakeSignature.signDetached(appearance, digest, signature, chain, null, null, null, 0, subfilter);
}
```

But probably your use case is a little bit different. Maybe you set special options or something... Can you please provide the sample code which fails?

Comment: Hi Alexander! Indeed my use case is a little bit different.  I've cretaed my own PDFAStamper based on iText PDFAStamper and added some extra features, but it is enough code involved to put it here. I use the preClose() method of PDFSigantureAppearance and there is the problem.  Thanks to the iText Mailing list, i know i'll need to add a human readable description in the  signature filed anottation, a recommendation of the PDF/A specification, not a requirement. I'm now on the way of how to implement.

Comment: Hi Jose! So you're adding some text annotation as a human readable description for the signature and then you get the exception "Annotation of type /Widget should have Contents key.". Right? Can you please send a portion of code how do you add such annotation?

Comment: No, before i wasn't adding this annotation description. Now i'm trying to add it but i need to extend the PDFSiganutreAppearance and overwrite the preClose() method and add the following line: sigField.put(PdfName.CONTENTS, new PdfString("some text", PdfObject.TEXT_UNICODE));

Comment: if i'll get to add this line i won't get the error "Annotation of type /Widget should have Contents key."

Comment: Not yet, if a i extend PDFSiganutreAppearance and overwrite the preClose() method adding that annotation i get over this exception but i get a wrong signed file.